# Unable To Remote Connect To Mongo CLI. Do different versions matter?

Tags: mongodb, tcp, netstat

I have three mongo instances running where one is a higher version. The reason is that mongochat02 is a newly provisioned server and the installed version came with 3.2.9.

1. mongochat01 - v3.0.8
2. mongochat02 - v3.2.9
3. mongochat03 - v3.0.8

I am able to issue `mongo --host` between mongochat01 and mongochat03 but cannot connect to mongochat02 from either mongochat01 and mongochat03.

Below is the example attempting to connect to mongochat02 from a working instance. It says connected but it never enters the shell and just gets stuck and eventually times out.

```
[richlu@chat03 ~]$ mongo --host mongochat02 --verbose
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: mongochat02:27017/test
2017-04-10T21:29:04.348+0000 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:mongochat02:27017
2017-04-10T21:29:04.350+0000 D COMMAND  [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2017-04-10T21:29:04.392+0000 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected to server mongochat02:27017 (10.8.129.114)
2017-04-10T21:29:04.434+0000 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected connection!
```

I am able to ping between the servers and nmap shows port 27017 is open for all three servers.

Firewalld shows 27017 as TCP open.

Issuing `netstat -tulpn | grep 27017` gives
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24456/mongod`

The `/etc/mongod.conf` files are the same, except the bindIp includes the server ip. I have tried commenting out the bindIp line and tried with 0.0.0.0.

I need help figuring out why I am unable to connect to the mongochat02 through the mongo client from the other servers. Do the versions matter much in this case? I was able to connect from my local Macbook running v3.2 to mongochat01 and mongochat03 just fine.

This connection issue is not allowing mongochat02 to become a replica set member.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the connection issue, please provide the **full** output of how you are connecting and the **exact** error message. I'm pretty sure that you should be able to connect a 3.2 shell to a 3.0 server.

Comment: @helmy I have added it by editing above. Thanks.